# Лаги на мультипоточном сервере и клиенте на UDP

Tags: java, многопоточность, udp

Пытаюсь написать видеочат на Java с использованием UDP. Дело в том, что при передаче кадров от клиентов к серверу и обратно, сервер, похоже, не справляется, и, как следствие, все очень сильно лагает.
Код клиента, где делается снимок:

```
while (true) {
            img = webcam.getImageFromWebcam();
            labelList.get(0).setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            try {
                sendDataThread(Utility.transformBufferedImageToBytes(img, userId));
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Метод `sendDataThread`:

```
void sendDataThread(final byte[] sendingData) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    udpSocket.sendData(sendingData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Методы отправки с клиента:

```
    private DatagramPacket formPacket(byte[] data) {
        return new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, serverPort);
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] sendingData) throws IOException {
        clientSocket.send(formPacket(sendingData));
    }
```

Код UDP-части сервера:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UDPWork {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> clientPortList;
    private DatagramSocket serverSocket;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 15000;
    private InetAddress ipAddress;

    void sendToClientsThread(byte[] data, int port) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sendToAnotherClients(data, port);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public UDPWork(int port, String ipAddress) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        this.ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(Utility.changeLastParameterIP(ipAddress));
        clientPortList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void startListening() throws IOException {
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                try {
                    listenClients();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
         }).start();
    }

    private void listenClients() throws IOException {
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = defineReceivePacket(buffer);
            sendToClientsThread(receiveData(receivePacket), receivePacket.getPort());
        }
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] data, int port) throws IOException {
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, port);
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }

    private void sendToAnotherClients(byte[] data, int port) throws IOException {
        for (int clientPort : clientPortList) {
            if (clientPort != port) { 
                sendData(data, clientPort); 
            }
        }
    }

    private DatagramPacket defineReceivePacket(byte[] buffer) {
        return new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    }

    private byte[] receiveData(DatagramPacket receivePacket) throws IOException {
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        return receivePacket.getData();
    }
}
```

Не понимаю, как можно улучшить работу сервера, чтобы кадры по 13кб передавались быстрее.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам на каждую отправку нужно создавать и стартовать новый `Thread`? Говорят, это довольно затратная операция. Посмотрите в сторону [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: @zRrr, а вы не подскажете, как правильно это реализовать? Битый час уже сижу..